# Analytical solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does this ODE have a known analytical solution?
$$
x(t)''\cdot x(t) = k
$$
Here $k$ is a real constant.

EDIT: using wolphram alpha, it is clear that it does have an [analytical solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%28t%29%27%27*x%28t%29%20%3D%201%2C%20plot%20x%28t%29). I'm still looking for a reference on how to find it though.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll update the question.

Comment: According to a CAS, there is solution for this ODE but it is a monster !

Answer (score 0):

This is too big for a comment thus I am writing it in the answer place.
$$x''(t)\cdot x(t)=k\Rightarrow x''(t)x'(t)=k\cdot\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}$$
Integrate both sides over $t$
\begin{align}\int x''(t)x'(t)\,dt=\int k\cdot\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\,dt&\Rightarrow \int x'(t)\,d(x'(t))=\int k\,d(\ln{x(t)})\\&\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(x'(t))^2=k\ln{x(t)}+c\end{align}
the above equality is equivalent to 
$$\exp{(x'(t))^2=c\cdot (x(t))^{2k}}$$
First notice that $x(t)$ can not be a polynomial function as the exponent of a polynomial grows faster than any polynomial raised to any power. $x(t)$ can not be a logarithmic function either as the left side would go to $1$ for large $t$ but the right side would go to infinity. I would suspect some form of trigonometric function like $\sin(t)$ or $\cos(t)$. However it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, working the awful formulas, you can show that $x(t)$ is such that $$t=c_2-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{c_1}{2 k}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{c_1+2
   k \log(x)}{k}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}$$

I hope and wish you enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Note that as long as $k$ is non-zero, $x$ cannot be zero anywhere, or else $x'' \cdot x = x'' \cdot 0 = 0 \ne k$.

Also, in the following, assume that $x > 0$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x'' \cdot x &=& k \\
x \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dt} &=& k \\
x \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dx} \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} &=& k \\
x x' \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dx} &=& k \\
x' \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dx} &=& k x^{-1} \\
\displaystyle \int x' \dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm dx} \ \mathrm dx &=& \displaystyle \int k x^{-1} \ \mathrm dx \\
\displaystyle \int x' \ \mathrm d\left(x'\right) &=& \displaystyle \int k x^{-1} \ \mathrm dx \\
\dfrac12\left(x'\right)^2 &=& k \ln x + C\\
x' &=& \sqrt{2k \ln x + C} \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} &=& \sqrt{2k \ln x + C} \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx} &=& \dfrac1{\sqrt{2k \ln x + C}} \\
\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx} \ \mathrm dx &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{\sqrt{2k \ln x + C}} \ \mathrm dx \\
t &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{\sqrt{2k \ln x + C}} \ \mathrm dx \\
\end{array}$$

Let $u = \sqrt{2k\ln x+C}$. Then, $x = \exp \left( \dfrac{u^2-C}{2k} \right)$ and $\mathrm dx = \dfrac u k \exp \left( \dfrac{u^2-C}{2k} \right) \ \mathrm du$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
t &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1{\sqrt{2k \ln x + C}} \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac1u \dfrac uk \exp \left( \dfrac{u^2-C}{2k} \right) \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac 1k \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right)\int \exp \left(\dfrac{u^2}{2k} \right) \ \mathrm du \\
\end{array}$$

For $-a^2 = \dfrac{u^2}{2k}$ to hold true, let $a = \dfrac{iu}{\sqrt{2k}}$. Then, $u=-ia\sqrt{2k}$ and $\mathrm du = -i\sqrt{2k} \ \mathrm da$.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
t &=& \displaystyle \frac 1k \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right)\int \exp \left(\dfrac{u^2}{2k} \right) \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac {-i\sqrt{2k}}k \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right)\int \exp \left(-a^2\right) \ \mathrm da \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac {-i\sqrt{2k\pi}}{2k} \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right) \operatorname{erf}\left(a\right) + D \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac {-i\sqrt{2k\pi}}{2k} \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right) \operatorname{erf}\left(\dfrac{iu}{\sqrt{2k}}\right) + D \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac {-i\sqrt{2k\pi}}{2k} \exp\left(\dfrac{-C}k\right) \operatorname{erf}\left(\dfrac{i\sqrt{2k\ln x+C}}{\sqrt{2k}}\right) + D \\
\end{array}$$